# Android 8.1 (Nexus) slow start up time. Not able to initialize class for SetValues

Tags: android

I recently noticed that my Android app took too long to start. The first screen shows up, but then it took a few seconds on Nexus (Android 8.1) to actually start the app. Google Play pre-launch report also shows start time 1-8 seconds (depends on device).

I reviewed LogCat on Debug session and noticed TONS of messages like the following. This is just small portion (may be around 15% of it):

```
05-22 12:57:50.752 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:50.759 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:50.789 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:50.854 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:50.856 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:50.898 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:50.900 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:50.913 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:50.958 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:50.960 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.032 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.036 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.055 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.125 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.128 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.169 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.171 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.184 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.231 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.233 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.279 2751-2751/foo W/zygote64: Verification of void myMainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) took 559.288ms
05-22 12:57:51.315 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.317 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.330 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.401 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.403 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.445 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.448 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.461 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.509 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.511 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.581 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.584 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.597 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.609 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$40>
05-22 12:57:51.669 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.671 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.712 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.714 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.727 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.733 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$40>
05-22 12:57:51.774 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.776 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.814 2751-2751/foo W/zygote64: Verification of void myMainActivity.XXX(yy.EventType, org.json.JSONObject) took 526.959ms
05-22 12:57:51.853 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.856 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:51.870 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:51.876 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$40>
05-22 12:57:51.886 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$35>
05-22 12:57:51.951 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:51.954 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:51.996 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$38>
05-22 12:57:51.998 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$39>
05-22 12:57:52.012 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$1>
05-22 12:57:52.017 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$40>
05-22 12:57:52.020 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$35>
05-22 12:57:52.066 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$21>
05-22 12:57:52.069 2751-2763/foo W/zygote64: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<myMainActivity$22>
05-22 12:57:52.129 2751-2751/foo W/zygote64: Verification of void myMainActivity.shareApp() took 308.999ms
```

What is going here? Why it took so long time? What is verification? What means tons of messages like "Not able to initialize class"? What is $XX number after the my activity name?

Note that after a few seconds the app starts without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Instant Run error. Clean your project to solve it.

Comment: I am also getting these errors after cleaning and then running in debug mode.